# Iterating Variant array in VBA with For Loop

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, for-loop

I tried to concat some strings in Excel with VBA.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
 Dim lenArray As Variant
 Dim strArray As Variant
 Dim strCombined As String
 Dim space As String

 lenArray = Range("D1:J1").Value
 strArray = Range("D2:J2").Value
 space = " "

 Dim i As Integer
 Dim temp As String
 For i = LBound(strArray) To UBound(strArray)
    strCombined = strCombined & strArray(i)
    temp = WorksheetFunction.Rept(space, CInt(lenArray(i)) - Len(strArray(i)))
    strCombined = strCombined & temp
 Next i

 Range("B4").Value = strCombined
End Sub
```

However, it always gives me out of bound error.

I also tried changing

```
For i = LBound(strArray) To UBound(strArray)
```

to

```
For i = 1 To 7
```

or

```
For i = 1 To 2
```

but it never works.

I have tried to iterate only the strArray with For Each and it would work.
Any help would be great.

Edited:
The spreadsheet I am using
[image]

Comment: strArray = Range("D2:J2").Value is a 2 dimentions array. if you put strArray(1,i) i think it will work. or check if you realy need a 2 dimentions array..

Comment: ^^^^ and `For i = LBound(strArray,2) To UBound(strArray,2)`

Comment: Breakpoints and Watch windows are very useful in these situations.

Comment: As you only want a list of values try  WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("D2:J2").Value).  This will give you a single dimension array from the psuedo two dimensional arra\y you get from Excel when you specify just a row or a column range.

Comment: Could you share the expected result in cell `B4` for the data shown in the screenshot?